# PDFSharp; Add SVG signature to PDF File

Tags: vb.net, pdf, svg, visual-studio-2015, stream

I'm using jSignature javascript to save a signature to SVG. Now I'm trying to put that SVG on top of a PDF document over a signature blank.

I'm able to do it by converting the SVG to a file, opening that file with SVG (SVG Rendering Library 2.3.0) and turning it into a stream which I then put onto the PDF with PDFSharp. My issue is that I can't get the SVG Library to load from a string. It has to load from a file. I'm pulling these signatures from a Database along with their form related data.

```
Dim FileText As String
Dim Bytes() As Byte
Using DB As New wotcDB
    FileText = (From t In DB.interviews Where t.ID = 1 Select t.Signature).FirstOrDefault
End Using

Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FileText)
Using DataStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(Bytes)
    svgDocument = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(DataStream) 'Issue
End Using
```

The error I get is as follows;

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Open' can be called with these arguments:
'Public Shared Overloads Function Open(Of T As {SvgDocument, New})(path As String) As T': Type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred.
'Public Shared Overloads Function Open(Of T As {SvgDocument, New})(stream As Stream) As T': Type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred.  WOTC-FE d:\Programming\Applications\frmDebug.vb 54  Active
```

I hate the idea of creating a file to convert to a graphic when the overloads clearly show that I can use streams. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you use `svgDocument.Draw()` when you put it into your PDF using PDFSharp?

Comment: Hi. Could you share the code for how you included the SVG stream into your pdf? This would be really useful to do... Even if you posted a new Q/A style question on StackOverflow on how to include an SVG in a pdf this way you'd probably get a lot of upvotes. as people are still trying to do this all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was something I already tried and though failed, but now it works. Since the type wasn't infer able, I had to declare it. I tried doing this as stream and it failed. Well today I decided to work through it and, I got it.

```
mySVG = SvgDocument.Open(Of SvgDocument)(newStream)
```

It's so obvious and I tripped over it. So to anyone else having this issue, that solves it. Please note that my program is running Option Explicit, Option Strict.

Answer (score 0):

Open the svg file in Notepad and check that it is actually using ASCII encoding. I think it is more likely that it is UTF-8. If so, use

```
Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileText)
```

instead.

Comment: The error I'm getting is at build time, not runtime.